# pass a symbol or special characters from model to view in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

my problem is strange
property EmployeePhone in the model has value "+96279000000"

so I pass it for javascript

```
$("#EmployeePhone").intlTelInput("setNumber", "@Model.EmployeePhone");
```

but the problem is at rendering time the value appears as

```
$("#EmployeePhone").intlTelInput("setNumber", "&#x2B;96279000000");
```

the expected result should be

```
$("#EmployeePhone").intlTelInput("setNumber", "+96279000000");
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `@Html.Raw(@Model.EmployeePhone);`.

Or:

```
function initialize() {
    var employeePhone= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.EmployeePhone));
}
...
$("#EmployeePhone").intlTelInput("setNumber", employeePhone);
```